# Tips for shooting a longer exposure in a car?

Tags: long-exposure

For example, a shot of the driver driving but with a slight blur to the driver without the car body itself being blurred (dashboard, seats, etc). Often when I give this a try the photo results in an overall blurryness,

what are some stabilization tips for this?

Thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to mount camera to ceiling, or floor. Mount to something as stationary as your objects of interest (e.g. dashboard), so car floor should be good enough. That is if you are talking about shooting inside the car.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=camera%20mount%20inside%20car&safe=off&es_sm=119&biw=1280&bih=705&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=LEwUVdrGMs-lyASk6oLICQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAA&dpr=1) might give you more ideas on how that can be achieved.

Comment: a dashboard of a moving car isn't exactly a rock steady tripod.

Comment: not steady as compared to what?

Comment: to anything that would allow a longish exposure ("with a slight blur to the driver") without shake. or a rock.

Comment: like what? If we talk about shooting inside moving car

Comment: yes, that is the problem. if i'd have a solution, i'd post my own answer.

Comment: I just mean, for example, a shot where the passenger was in a soft blur while the rest of the car was stationary. Today I am going to try a tripod in the center of the car, rather than the side where it was slightly tilted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: in my physical model of car dashboard is as stationary as the floor or windows. Front seats, when occupied, can move around a bit. @ths you just said that in same way as "earth is not rock steady", which is true in some circumstances. Out of context that is useless comment.

Comment: @Jay Tripod might require additional stabilization, but what about suction-based glass mounts? If camera is light enough

Comment: @ths the dashboard is generally steady in relation to the windshield, seats and doors, thus holding those items _relatively_ shake free while capturing the motion of the driver in comparison.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a (multi) suction cup mount that would be used to mount video cameras to the windows for in-car shots.

Comment: in my experience, cars *vibrate*.

Comment: Great ideas! Thanks everyone! I'm going to look into these